# Manually install a directory of python packages

Tags: python, python-2.7, site-packages

My normal packages are located in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

I have another loose hanging folder named `dist-packages` that contains several custom python packages taken from a different VM.

Does anyone know if a simple `cp` the contents of of `dist-packages` to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` do the trick? I don't want to do it and then have to manually sort out which files don't belong if it doesn't work.

Edit:
Or ideally a way for python2.7 to reference the path of custom `dist-packages`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not guaranteed to be able to do that.

IF the versions of python from both the parent directories of the two `dist-packages` is the same, then it will work, but you have to make sure it's the exact same version. Provided they are, you can do:

```
$ cp -r [path_to_loose_folder]/dist-packages/* /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
```